# How do I use the find method in tables

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the find method on a listObject (a table) with no luck. I've been searching for some solution with the same result. The only ansers I find is using the find method with a range object, which is not my case.

I would appreciate any information or example on how to find data in a listObject.

Edit: here the code

```
Sub WA_suchen_test()
Dim WA_Nummer As Long
Dim pos As Byte
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim rng_anfang As Range
Dim rng_ende As Range
Dim i As Long

WA_Nummer = 1356794
Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("offene_WA").ListObjects("tb_offene_WA")

rng_anfang = lo.Range.Find(WA_Nummer, lo.ListColumns("WA") _
.DataBodyRange(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, True)

rng_ende = lo.ListColumns("WA").DataBodyRange.Find(WA_Nummer, rng_anfang, _
xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, True)
MsgBox rng_anfang.Address & " / " & rng_ende.Address

End Sub
```

The macro throws error nr. 91 after the `Set`instruction.

(Please do not hesitate with the `pos` definition, it's gonna be used later in the code.)

Thanks,
Charlie

Comment: YOu need to use `Set` when assigning the result of a `Find` operation to a `Range` variable. Also, the arguments to your first `Find` operation don't make sense. You seem to have one too many - looks like you should remove `lo.ListColumns("WA")`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rory, that was it!!! I tried the arguments as is and it works fine, I just want to search in one column, not the whole table. If you write your comment as an answer, I will gladly mark it as solved.

Comment: I've updated my answer below to include the comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Listobject` has several range properties you can use with Find:

`Range`, `DataBodyRange`, `HeaderRowRange` (and `InsertRowRange` though that is an unlikely choice).

Edit:
Looking at your code above, you need to use `Set` when assigning the result of a `Find` operation to a `Range` variable. Also, the arguments to your first `Find` operation don't make sense. You seem to have one too many - looks like you should remove `lo.ListColumns("WA")`

Comment: Thanks @rory, but I'm already aware of that. The problem is, although I use `Range` I get an error Message saying the Method is not supported.
Example:
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("offene_WA").ListObjects("tb_offene_WA").Range.Find(value,Range)`
Or maybe I am using it wrong?

Comment: @elserra add your code to your original post and re-word your question to show the example.

Comment: I suggest you add your full code to the question, because that should work (depending on what that second `Range` is meant to be)